# Trying to send FormData to backend API with React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, form-data, use-effect

I have a handle change function which should be uploading a photo, title and text to formData

```
const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    const value = name === "photo" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
    this.postData.set(name, value);
    console.log(this.postData);
  };
```

Here is the JSX where I try to upload the photo (there are similar input tags for text and title)

```
 <div className="flex flex-wrap mb-6">
          <div className="relative w-full appearance-none label-floating">
            <input
              className="tracking-wide py-2 px-4 mb-3 leading-relaxed appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 rounded focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
              id="photo"
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              value={state.photo}
              onChange={handleChange("photo")}
            />
            <label
              for="name"
              className="absolute tracking-wide py-2 px-4 mb-4 opacity-0 leading-tight block top-0 left-0 cursor-text"
            >
              Photo
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

postData I'm trying to initiate in a useEffect hook

```
 useEffect(() => {
      this.postData = new FormData();
  });
```

then on the onlclick of a button I call my createPost() which does an axios call to my backend to create a post with my formData

```
 const createPost = (postData) => {
    // console.log("user ID from route params", props.match.params.userId);
    const userId = props.match.params.userId;
    const token = isAuthenticated().token;
    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    };
    const bodyParameters = {
      key: "value",
    };
    const body = postData;
    axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost:8000/post/new/${userId}`,
        bodyParameters,
        config,
        body
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            title: response.data,
          }));
          console.log(response.data);
        } else {
          console.log("Some error ocurred");
          setState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            redirect: true,
          }));
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

it's not working what am I missing?

Comment: what is "this.postData"?

Comment: Hi Roy thanks for your reply. Well, I'm trying to make postData into a FormData object, I thought here it'd be like doing a componentDidMount. I fill postData later with the photo, title and text from the form inputs

Comment: I think it better to use useState hook

Comment: I see. So Update state with values from the form inputs and then add them to the FormData? How would that be done? Then how do I pass the FormData to my CreatePost function?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better if you created the form data object just before calling the api.

1. Store the photo uploaded in a state
2. On click of the submit button, call a function that creates a form data object. Add your photo to this form data object and then call the API.

Comment: Thanks very much Rhea. I'm getting the input vallues in state but when I add them to the FormData() it doesn't seem to be working

`

const createPost = () => {
    console.log("state title", state.title);
    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.set("title", state.title);
    postData.set("body", state.body);
    postData.append("photo", state.photo);
    console.log(postData);
  };

`

Comment: Awesome! Mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem! :)